# como encerrar o input quando usar o .hasNext() em java?

Tags: java

Estou usando um código que utiliza `Scanner` (que dei o nome de `input`) e utiliza `while(input.hasNextLine())`, porém ele não pára de pedir entradas, sei que tem um comando especifico para isso (algo como `/n`) mas não consigo me recordar.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Apresente seu código para vermos o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá você pode fazer algo assim:

```
Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
//seu código de entrada
if (ler.equals("")) {
        ler.close();
    }   
}
```